# How do I push dates into an array by week?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing this code that maps dates by day and pushes them into an array:

```
rtn_ary = []
(2.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
  rtn_ary << {period: date}
end
```

How can I write the code if my expected result is based on weeks instead of days like this?

```
[[{:period=>Mon, 28 Sep 2015}, {:period=>Tue, 05 Oct 2015}, {:period=>Tue, 12 Oct 2015}]
```

Comment: What is `weeks`, `ago`, `to_date`?

Comment: Your expected result is invalid.

Comment: The example I showed is the expected result I wish I can get, because for now I am getting an array based on each days. Is there a way I could do to change the array to the result I want?

Comment: Yup this is a helper i created.

Comment: this `{:period=>"Tue, 05 Oct 2015"}` is valid this `{:period=>Tue, 05 Oct 2015}` isn't.

Comment: Why is this not valid?

Comment: `tue, 05 Oct 2015` is not valid because it has no type. The most common types are string, integer and boolean (true, false)

Comment: There is an even more critical reason the expected result is invalid. And if the OP cannot figure out why, then the OP does not qualify as a programmer, or cannot do any kind of professional job.

Comment: @Cyzanfar Thanks for giving constructive explanation. I am still learning and this is the code from railscasts tutorial, so just wondering why it is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution could be to iterate by 7 days instead of 1 day:

```
rtn_ary = (2.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).step(7).map do |date|
  {period: date}
end
=> [{:period=>Mon, 28 Sep 2015}, {:period=>Mon, 05 Oct 2015}]
```

More info about step: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-step

Answer (score 1):

To get what you want you'll need an additional step:

```
(2.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
     rtn_ary << {period: date.to_formatted_s(:long)}
 end
```

The `to_formatted_s()` method convert the date into a formatted string and takes a parameter which will define how the date will be formatted into a string.

```
date.to_formatted_s(:short)         # => "10 Nov"
date.to_formatted_s(:number)        # => "20071110"
date.to_formatted_s(:long)          # => "November 10, 2007"
date.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)  # => "November 10th, 2007"
date.to_formatted_s(:rfc822)        # => "10 Nov 2007"
date.to_formatted_s(:iso8601)       # => "2007-11-10"
```

Take a look at the rails [Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html)